# Different Indexes with different query duration

Tags: mysql

I had the following table that holds phone contacts of users.

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts_phone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playerPhone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `friendPhone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `by_contact` (`playerPhone`,`friendPhone`),
  KEY `by_id` (`playerPhone`),
  KEY `by_phone` (`friendPhone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I built the next query that returns mutual friends of my friends:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE phones.*, COUNT(phones.friendPhone) AS mutual_friends
FROM (SELECT cp2.friendPhone
    FROM contacts_phone cp1
    JOIN contacts_phone cp2 ON cp1.friendPhone= cp2.playerPhone
    WHERE cp1.playerPhone = 'PHONE_NUMBER') phones
WHERE phones.friendPhone IN (SELECT friendPhone
        FROM contacts_phone
        WHERE playerPhone = 'PHONE_NUMBER')
GROUP BY phones.friendPhone
```

Until this point everything was ok :)

As our product grew we have collected 13M rows to this table and had a product requirement to add the users id to this table. So I made the next change:

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts_phone` 
ADD COLUMN `cid` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `id`,
DROP INDEX `by_contact` ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `by_contact` (`playerPhone` ASC, `friendPhone` ASC, `cid` ASC),
ADD INDEX `by_cid` (`cid` ASC);
```

I added the user's id (cid) to the table and filled the missing data. part of the rows didn't have id so I had to use  `DEFAULT NULL`.

I built a different but pretty similar query but now using cid instead.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE phones.*, COUNT(phones.friendPhone) AS mutual_friends
FROM (SELECT cp2.friendPhone
    FROM contacts_phone cp1
    JOIN contacts_phone cp2 ON cp1.friendPhone = cp2.playerPhone
    WHERE cp1.cid = 'USER_ID') phones
WHERE phones.friendPhone IN (SELECT friendPhone
        FROM contacts_phone
        WHERE cid = 'USER_ID')
GROUP BY phones.friendPhone
```

I expected to get a similar query duration but the result was that when querying with cid the duration is doubled.

What am I missing out? Do I have something wrong in my design? 
Could it be because of the nullable index?

Comment: Create index by `(cid, friendPhone)` instead of by single `(cid)`.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for the quick reply. can you please elaborate on why your answer will solve my problem and why my way didn't work.

Comment: Look at the subquery in WHERE. Server needs check for `cid` in index and obtain primary records numbers, then get `friendPhone` from table by this numbers. When composite index exists server do not need to read a table, it can take `friendPhone` from the index immediately. Disk operations are slow... decrease them ~ twice decreases elapsed time ~ twice.

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: Is it `playerphone` or is it `playerId`?  Or `cid`?  What is the minimal set of columns (other than `id` that is `UNIUQUE`)?  I see multiple issues with the indexes, but I want to understand the columns before presenting an Answer.

Comment: @RickJames you are right I mixed up the names when I copied the original query. thanks for that. there is no playerId I meant to write playerPhone.
I edited the question please take a look again. I'm using MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7

Comment: So, the combination "(`playerPhone`,`friendPhone`)" no longer needs to be `UNIQUE`?  (I am trying to understand the intent of the schema and query.)  One optimization is to try to get rid of subqueries.

Comment: In the first query, a "user" seems to be identified uniquely by his "playerphone".  In the last query, `cid` has taken over that role.  What is the purpose of `playerphone` now?

Comment: Would it help to have `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`?  (With the change in indexes, there can now be duplicates, I think.)  Please state, in English, what the query is trying to achieve.

Comment: @RickJames 
1. the combination "(playerPhone,friendPhone)" has to be unique. I want to prevent the chance that the client will send to the server multiple combinations.
2. the 2 queries only separated here for the purpose of comparison of the duration. In real life i'll have OR between `playerphone` and `cid`.
3. distinct won't work, the duplication of the rows is what need in order to count the mutual friends. And that is what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm querying all of the friends of my friends in the from subquery and count all of the duplication as mutuals. then i'm filtering just the ones that are my friends by the where subquery.

Comment: @Akina any insight after editing my question? i don't see any difference between `cid` and `playerPhone` they each has seperated index. why playerPhone is faster? what is the difference?

Comment: If "(playerPhone,friendPhone)" is unique, then don't drop that index, nor start another unique index with the same columns.  `OR` has serious negative impact on performance; show us that query.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with the latest version.  Is a "friend" identified via a "phone"?  Or an "id"?  Please tighten up the statement of the problem.  Instead of focusing on failed attempts; clearly state the goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95703/discussion-between-rami-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- A "user" is uniquely associated with a "phone"
- A "user" having a "friend" (also a "user") is indicated in a table that includes `UNIQUE(personPhone, friendPhone)`.  (`UNIQUE` is used to prevent redundant entries.)  (in table `contacts_phone`)

Then the number of friends that 'Rami' and 'Rick' have in common is found

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM contacts_phone AS me
    JOIN contacts_phone AS you  USING (friendPhone)
    WHERE  me.personPhone = 'Rick'
      AND you.personPhone = 'Rami'
```

And the `UNIQUE` index above serves this query well.

Another approach:

```
SELECT friendPhone FROM (
    ( SELECT friendPhone FROM contacts_phone WHERE personPhone = 'Rick' )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT friendPhone FROM contacts_phone WHERE personPhone = 'Rami' )
                        ) AS x
GROUP BY friendPhone
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This finds all our common friends.  Wrap a `SELECT COUNT(*) ( ... ) AS y` to get the count.  (This is likely to be slower.)

**How many different friends Rami's friends have.**  First, let's decide on some details using this example:

```
Rami's friends:  A, B, C, X

A's friends:     D, Rami, C
B's friends:     E, F, A   (guess B doesn't like Rami back)
C's friends:     A, D, Rami
X's friends:     Y, Z

Rami's friends' friends:  D(twice), Rami(twice), C, E, F, A(twice)
```

Should the count be:

```
9 -- but that includes dups
6 -- but that goes back to Rami
5 -- excludes Rami, but includes 1st level A and C
3 (D, E, F) -- Maybe this is the count you want??
```

The desired output is:

```
A  2
B  0
C  1
X  0
```

**Friend of friend**

Let's break the problem into 2 steps.  First, see if this gives you the list of friend-of-friends, together with their counts:

```
SELECT  c2.friendPhone AS friend_of_friend,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM  contacts_phone AS c1
    JOIN  contacts_phone AS c2  ON c2.personPhone = c1.friendPhone
    WHERE  c1.personPhone = 'Rami'
    GROUP BY  c2.friendPhone;
```

That should include people that are not directly your friends.  So, let's filter those out.  One way is thus:

```
SELECT  fof.friend_of_friend, fof.cnt
    FROM  ( ... the above query ... ) AS fof
    JOIN  contacts_phone AS c1  ON x.personPhone = c1.friendPhone
    WHERE  c1.personPhone = 'Rami';
```

(Other approaches might involve `HAVING` or `EXISTS`.)

Comment: This query will return only the sum of mutual friends between Rami and Rick.
The query that I built return mutual friends for all of my friends.

Comment: @Rami - OK, that takes an extra layer of `SELECT` -- Do you want counts?  Or the actual `Phones`?

Comment: the mutuals friends are actually counts

Comment: @Rami - In the example that I spelled out, what is the desired count?

Comment: The desired result would be: A-2, B-0, C-1

Comment: @Rami - You need 3 rows out output?  And D,E,F (friends of friends) are not relevant?  I don't see any substantive difference between A and C; each has you as a friend, plus one of your friends.

Comment: yes 3 rows A,B,C just the friends. C is shown once at my friends lists(From A), A is shown twice (From B and C)

Comment: @Rami - see if the code I added solves the Problem.

Comment: Thanks Rick. The query you posted really more performant than mine. although it looks pretty similar. can you please explain why this minor changes as big impact? by the way, querying with player phone is still faster than cid (0.3sec vs 0.4sec) and this is my original question, how can 2 indexes have a different result.

Comment: @Rami - I have 2 blogs that may help in understanding indexes, especially "composite" (multi-column) indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1  and  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql